# BLE scanning stops device discovery when the screen is locked for Samsung S6

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app to scan for the peripheral devices using the Android phone.

When the Application tested using Samsung S6 device (Model used are Indian, EU and US version), I have seen that the device stopped discovering the BLE devices during scanning as soon as the phone screen is locked.

It almost took 4-5 hours to resume the discovery when the phone kept in same locked state.

Configuration Details:
Lollypop Scanner with scan filter UUID's using Low Power Mode. 
ignore Battery Optimization was set to True.
Phone screen locked after some time when the scanning was started.
Samsung Models used: SM-G920F, SM-G920A

Test results :
The app was able to see the discovery when it was in the foreground and device discovery stopped immediately when the phone screen was locked.

Important Note : The same application is working fine on Samsung S7,S8,S9 and pixel

Comment: if you want it to stay alive while locked you really need to write a service

Comment: Hi Paul, The scanning is started using the service. This application is working fine with S7,S8,S9 and Pixel but on S6 this issue has been observed.

Comment: It has nothing to do about Service. What you need to do is to use a filter for your BLE scan. Otherwise Android stops the scan when the screen is turned off.

Comment: Hi Emil, I know the UUIDS of the services used in the BLE devices. So while starting the scan they are used in the filter. I have taken care of this part.

Comment: We have certainly found that many devices inexplicably turn off bluetooth - apparently to save power / increase battery life. Unfortunately I we have never found a solution other than to pick a phone that is less broken.

Comment: Yes, that's true but I have seen this behavior even when the phone was plugged in.